Determine the nilradical of $K[X]/(X^n)$
Let $K$ be a field, define $A:=K[X]/(X^n)$, I want to show that the nilradical $$\mathfrak{N}_A=\{P \in A | \exists n : P^n=0\}=(X)$$
My Problem is that I don‘t seem to use $K$ being a field.
My proof goes as follows:
$K$ is a field, so in particular an integral domain, so $\mathfrak{N}_K=\{0\}$. We also have that for $P‘ \in K[X]$ is nilpotent, if and only if all its coefficients are. Thus $\mathfrak{N}_{K[x]}=\{0\}$.
So if we take a look at $P \in K[X]/(X^n)$, such that $P \neq 0$; we have that $P$ (in terms of some representative) is of following form:
$$P=a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+ \dots +a_0$$
Now if there was some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $P^m=0$ its equivalent to $X^n| P^m$, thus $X^n|a_0^m$, so $a_0=0$. This implies $X|P$, so $P \in (X)$.
So if $Q \in (X)$, there trivially exists an $k\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $Q^k$ is divisible by $X^n$, so $Q \in \mathfrak{N}_A$.
This yields the $\mathfrak{N}_A=(X)$.
Did I use $K$ being a field unknowingly or is my proof faulty?

Your proof is fine, you showed a slightly stronger statement, where $K$ is only an integral domain. Your proof could be slightly simplified for $K$ a field, but there's nothing wrong with it.

@anankElpis thank you for the feedback. Where could it be simplified?

Your remarks about the nilpotent elements in $K[X]$ are not required for the proof.

The conclusion of $X^n \mid a_0^m$ is unclear.

Actually you don't need any assumption on $K$ to compute the nilradical.
Let $R$ be any commutative ring. Then the nilradical of $R[X]/\langle X^n \rangle$ is $\langle \mathrm{Nil}(R),[X] \rangle$.
Proof 1. The inclusion $\supseteq$ is immediate. To prove the converse, assume that $[p] \in R[X] / \langle X^n \rangle$ is nilpotent, where $p \in R[X]$. Write $p = a + Xq$ with $a \in R$ and $q \in R[X]$. Since $[X]$ is nilpotent, it follows that $[a]$ is nilpotent. Since $R \to R[X]/\langle X^n \rangle$ is injective, it follows that $a \in R$ is nilpotent, and we are done.
Proof 2. The nilradical in general is equal to the intersection of all prime ideals. The prime ideals of $R[X]/\langle X^n \rangle$ correspond to the prime ideals of $R[X]$ that contain $X^n$, which then must contain $X$ (by the definition of a prime ideal). So they correspond to the prime ideals of $R[X] / \langle X \rangle \cong R$. This shows that $\mathrm{Nil}(R[X])$ is the preimage of $\mathrm{Nil}(R)$ under $R[X]/\langle X^n \rangle \to R$, $X \mapsto 0$, i.e. $\langle \mathrm{Nil}(R), [X] \rangle$.
In particular, as soon as $R$ is a reduced ring (meaning $\mathrm{Nil}(R)=0$), we have $\mathrm{Nil}(R[X]/\langle X^n \rangle) = \langle [X] \rangle$.

Oh well, I conjectured that, but since my task was only evaluate the nilradical in the $K$ is a field case, I wasn’t sure if it was correct. Great input, thanks!
